# Error on copy some text to clipboard in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I am trying to copy a text to a clipboard using below command:

```
Clipboard.SetText(textToCopy);
```

but an exception is thrown:

[image]

Anyway, text is correctly copied to clipboard. I can catch the exception so the user does not see it but I would like to know what is happening.

Comment: Please don't post exceptions as screenshots. Post them as text, especially the stack trace and the `HRESULT` value.

Comment: See this: https://twitter.com/davkean/status/1004518747988586496

Comment: Ok, I will take it into account. Thx.